# How to limit timeslot selection to one day in Fullcalendar Jquery?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I want to select time slots and create event only on the particular start date. the selection should not be enable for next or previous days.
For Example in the below image I have started the event on Mon 11/10 (6.30 am) the end time should be within the same day. The User should not be able to select next days or previous days.
In Google calendar you can see this feature.

Kindly share how can I do this here.
Thanks for you time.

[image]

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077098/how-to-limit-events-per-time-slot-in-fullcalendar

Comment: @SimarjeetSinghPanghlia Still I didn't get it. The code in that link gives error.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to prevent the events from spanning across multiple days on resize. I don't understand if it is the same as your issue.

In the calendar configuration I set:

```
eventConstraint : {
        start : '0:00',
        end : '24:00'
},
```

Reference: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventConstraint/

Answer (score 3):

you could use

```
selectConstraint:{
  start: '00:01', 
  end: '23:59', 
},
```

Comment: I was facing the same problem, your answer worked perfectly . Thanks @Saurav Dangol

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectable/), setting the **selectable** property to *false* should be able to help you achieve that.